# Wireguard fails to build kernel module

Tags: ubuntu-minimal, wireguard

Installed Wireguard on Ubuntu 18.04.5

Kernel is:

```
uname -r
4.15.0
```

When I checked

```
# dkms status 
wireguard, 1.0.20201112: added
```

Trying to build Wireguard:

```
dkms build wireguard/1.0.20200506
```

Gave the following log:

```
DKMS make.log for wireguard-1.0.20201112 for kernel 4.15.0-140-generic (x86_64)
Fri Apr  9 07:32:49 UTC 2021
make: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-140-generic'
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/wireguard/1.0.20201112/build/main.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/wireguard/1.0.20201112/build/noise.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/wireguard/1.0.20201112/build/device.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/wireguard/1.0.20201112/build/peer.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/wireguard/1.0.20201112/build/timers.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/wireguard/1.0.20201112/build/queueing.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/wireguard/1.0.20201112/build/send.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/wireguard/1.0.20201112/build/receive.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/wireguard/1.0.20201112/build/socket.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/wireguard/1.0.20201112/build/peerlookup.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/wireguard/1.0.20201112/build/allowedips.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/wireguard/1.0.20201112/build/ratelimiter.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/wireguard/1.0.20201112/build/cookie.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/wireguard/1.0.20201112/build/netlink.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/wireguard/1.0.20201112/build/crypto/zinc/chacha20/chacha20.o
  PERLASM /var/lib/dkms/wireguard/1.0.20201112/build/crypto/zinc/chacha20/chacha20-x86_64.S
  AS [M]  /var/lib/dkms/wireguard/1.0.20201112/build/crypto/zinc/chacha20/chacha20-x86_64.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/wireguard/1.0.20201112/build/crypto/zinc/poly1305/poly1305.o
  PERLASM /var/lib/dkms/wireguard/1.0.20201112/build/crypto/zinc/poly1305/poly1305-x86_64.S
  AS [M]  /var/lib/dkms/wireguard/1.0.20201112/build/crypto/zinc/poly1305/poly1305-x86_64.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/wireguard/1.0.20201112/build/crypto/zinc/chacha20poly1305.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/wireguard/1.0.20201112/build/crypto/zinc/blake2s/blake2s.o
  AS [M]  /var/lib/dkms/wireguard/1.0.20201112/build/crypto/zinc/blake2s/blake2s-x86_64.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/wireguard/1.0.20201112/build/crypto/zinc/curve25519/curve25519.o
gcc: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs> for instructions.
scripts/Makefile.build:330: recipe for target '/var/lib/dkms/wireguard/1.0.20201112/build/crypto/zinc/curve25519/curve25519.o' failed
make[1]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/wireguard/1.0.20201112/build/crypto/zinc/curve25519/curve25519.o] Error 4
make[1]: *** Deleting file '/var/lib/dkms/wireguard/1.0.20201112/build/crypto/zinc/curve25519/curve25519.o'
Makefile:1590: recipe for target '_module_/var/lib/dkms/wireguard/1.0.20201112/build' failed
make: *** [_module_/var/lib/dkms/wireguard/1.0.20201112/build] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-140-generic'
```

I don't know how to fix this issue. I successfully installed wireguard on local ubuntu 18.04 without any troubles, but on VPS it's couldn't.